# While recording the Script in Jmeter " The security certificate presented with this website security certificate"

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to record the script in jmeter and I'm getting error message in IE browser.

```
The security certificate presented with this website security certificate
```

Comment: maybe you also want to ask a question - like "what does this message mean" or something?

Comment: Look at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this error:

[image: JMeter Proxy Error]

This is normal and you can just click `Proceed to this website`.

When you start JMeter's proxy it generates self-signed SSL certificate in order to be able to decrypt and record HTTPS requests. Internet explorer warns you about the certificate (it is not signed by a trusted company), but this is something you can expect as the certificate was created by you when you started the proxy.

So it is fine to ignore this message.

See the following reference material:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (especially **HTTPS recording and certificates** section)
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

Comment: Hi @dmitri-t,

I just click Proceed to this website but the response is connection timed out like this:

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at java.net.`

what should I do? Please help.